# Not show the page name in the address bar

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to change what is displayed in the addressbar from "websitename.com/index.php" to "www.websitename.com" so I want it to not show the "index.php" part and I want it to include the "www." part.

Edit: I managed to not show the "index.php", just still looking for a way to show the "www." when you only type "websitename.com"

Comment: or, even easier: google remove index.php from url first result: https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html

Comment: Also just realized you haven't specified what web server software you are using: i.e. apache or nginx?

Comment: Thanks all for the replies, I'm looking into mod_rewrite now, but does this also allow me to have "www." in front of the websitename?

Comment: I am running Apache btw

Comment: Thanks Justin, I used your link and I got the "index.php" gone in the address bar, I'm only still wondering how I can get the "www." in front of the website without having to type it